# Realistic Ocean Shears

Tags: fluid-dynamics, specific-reference, climate-science, oceanography

I was wondering if anyone could point me to published data on the vertical structure of strong ocean currents, such as the Gulf Stream.  I am primarily interested in the mean current profile as a function of depth (in the core of the current) near the surface, which go on to estimate vertical shears.

Comment: Hi Zamoura. Welcome to Physics SE. 
I'm not sure if this is the proper site for this question. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: There are only two groups that I know of that work with ocean currents (besides the US Navy for their subs) http://www.oscar.noaa.gov/ and http://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/global/

Comment: @Ali why it is not the proper site for this question?

Comment: In near surface, it's probably change in function of the sea sates condition and meteorology condition.

Comment: It seems your field is in Physical Oceanography? If so would you consider helping out the geoscience proposal by committing to use it? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/geoscience

Comment: I did do that, thanks for letting me know.  If anyone has anything else to add please do!  I really appreciate it.

Comment: What about using ODV (http://odv.awi.de/) I am sure you can find some data sets that will have the vertical structure in all sorts of worlds currents, particularly the Gulf stream and the Kuroshio.